# UNEXPECTED hiding of Status bar on two pages in app

Tags: android, statusbar

I made an application, all working good but the STATUS BAR  is not showing on some of my pages.

Can i get an idea about how to resolve it ?

This is My manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Customer WOW App"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: post code also manifest file

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar have a look !

Comment: you gotta post your main activity and the manifest files to solve your issue

Comment: @johnrao07 you want my java class of that page which is rendering issue and the manifest file right ?

Comment: yup...thats what I meant

Comment: @chawla.19 Are you using the same **theme** for all your activities?

Comment: @Rami yes i am using theme for all my activities.

Comment: Please post you full manifest file and the class where the status bar is not working